# Views: filter content by a field (username) of someone who has never logged in

Tags: 7, views

We have an application that has a field to enter usernames of people who have never logged in before.

When these users log in, we want to filter these applications in a view to match their currently logged in username.

Is this possible?

Detailed explanation:

There are two roles: student and faculty. Both have sections to fill on the same node. Field permissions hides the fields of the other role. We want students to see the node that a faculty created for them in a view when they log in. Can the faculty fill out a username field (student has not logged in before) so that the view will list only the content assigned to the student?

I was thinking of using contextual filters on a taxonomy term with a default value of a PHP script that grabs the current username. However, I don't know if this is possible/practical and the PHP code I found online didn't end up working. Any thoughts or ideas?

two scripts I've tried:

```
global $user;
$user_uid = user_load($user->uid);
$myuserid = $user_uid->field_std_user_id['und']['0']['value'];
return $myuserid;

global $user;
$term= user_load($user->uid)->field_std_user_id;
return $term['und'][0]['tid'];
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the entire situation. Are students already registered? Do you want to list users that aren't actually users yet?

Comment: What Drupal version? Please tag your question with a Drupal version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Views' exposed filter to filter by username. But you will have to do some coding to get current user's name in the field.